# Perforce shelv another users open files

Tags: perforce

We had the situation that we needed to modify a file that was checked out by another user. We usually have the policy to revert the users file, if it's after hours.

`p4 revert //depot/test.txt -C usersWorkspace`

However, as this is destructive, is there a way to actually shelv that users files?

Answer (score 3):

You would need physical access to that user's workspace in order to be able to access their local file and shelve it.  If you do have the ability to login to their machine as them, the best solution would be to also run the `p4 shelve` and `p4 revert` commands as them, leaving their workspace in a consistent state with the change safely shelved.

Remotely reverting the file via the `-C` flag doesn't destroy the local file; the user can pick up where they left off by running `reconcile`.

If this is in fact a text file, I'd suggest rethinking your (presumed) usage of the `+l` filetype.  Ideally, one user checking out a file should not block other users in the first place, and text diffs are generally very easy to merge.  If this is *not* a mergeable file, note that having the change shelved doesn't really help the user, since they won't be able to merge it with whatever got submitted while they were away!